# Angular Routing not working - blank screen

Tags: angularjs-routing

I am stymied by this issue.  For some reason the Angular routing is not working at all.  I simply get a blank screen.  All of the modules are loading, there is no error in the console, and if I enter Angular in the console, it works.  Yet, I get a blank screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>QuickCalcs</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ng-animation.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/qcController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="qc">

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>


-----------------------------
app.js file is:
-----------------------------
var qc = angular.module('qc', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource'
    ]);

qc.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'qcController'
}). 
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'qcController'
}).
    when('/results', {
        templateUrl: 'views/results.html',
        controller: 'qcController'
}). 
    otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'views/home.html'
});
}]);
-----------------------------
Directory structure is:
-----------------------------
```

qc
    /js
        app.js
    /views
        home.html
        results.html
    /controllers
        qccontroller.js

Answer (score 0):

You must link your page to the application module 
in the html tag like this:

< html lang="en" **ng-app="qc"** />